# How to run a query with a large amount of data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query on `XAMPP` `MySQL`.

I have 2 tables.

The first table has about 30k rows, every row is a specific SKU.
(SKU is a number assigned to a product)

The second table has 100k rows. It has all the data for every SKU.

My aim is to gather all the data for every SKU from the first table.

This is what I did so far:

```
    SELECT v.sku
        ,t.TTC_TYP_ID
        ,t.CAR_BRAND
        ,t.CAR_MODEL
        ,t.CAR_TYP
        ,t.CAR_BODY
        ,t.CAR_OF_YEAR
        ,t.CAR_TO_YEAR
        ,t.CAR_KW
        ,t.CAR_PM
        ,t.CAR_CC
        ,t.ART_NAME
        ,t.ART_GROUP
        ,t.PARTS_INFO
        ,t.TERMS_OF_USE
        ,t.ART_CROSS
    FROM volvo_skus v
    JOIN truckpartstest t ON v.sku = t.oe_number
```

I tried to connect v.SKU and t.oe_number because they are the same, just a different name for the column.

It's all good if I run this script with a small amount of data.
But when I try to run this script with a real amount of data, XAMPP shows a 'Loading' bar and nothing happens. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Comment: Which of these columns is the primary key? If they are not keys then are they indexed?

Comment: check if indexes are created.

Comment: A table `JOIN` with 130k total rows is not a "large amount" of data. Depending on your hardware, execution time should range from almost instant to just a few seconds. If your application is hanging, there's likely another problem.

Comment: use the command prompt, i assume you are using windows os, so you have to connect to your mysql server and provide the username and password, xampp installer should have added your mysql bin to the PATH environment variable. If your query works in the command prompt, check your xampp timeout configuration

Comment: How to create indexes without screwing up the data? Just tried to create an index for the column and all the rows are now set to '0'.

Comment: Usually you don't ever need to request **all** data. Usually you should have some `WHERE` and `LIMIT`. Because without `WHERE` and without `LIMIT` your `JOIN` makes very few sense.  You can get all your data just from `truckpartstest ` ;-). \If you still need to get **all** you should measure query execution time and data fetching time.

Comment: It worked out after indexing the columns. But now it stucks at export window